# How do you remove the academic and demos sections from the main page of the Academic hugo theme when using blogdown?

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I created a site (https://www.dsobolew.me/) using blogdown and the Academic hugo theme. I want to remove the Academic and Demos sections on the main page so the first thing that appears is the Biography section. I see the markdown sections for each in the content/home folder. I expected to see a way to change the main page in the config.toml file but do not. How is this updated?

Answer (score 2):

Duh. There is a setting in each md file within content/home that can be set = false.

Answer (score 1):

Also for other people interested in that question:

They changed it in the meantime. Yes, the md files are under content/home but you have to add the option "active" now yourself (in an old version I used, the active option was already in the file).

So for example you take projects.md and just add the line:
active: false

Answer (score 0):

In folder content you find the individual pages as `.md`. There set `active: false`.

For example you don't want content/home/hero.md

```
---
active: false
widget: hero

(...)
```

If you wish to remove to content/home/demo.md (by default says "Welcome to the demo of the academic resumé template for Wowchemy ..."), note line 7 by default there's already an `active: true` that needs to be removed or changed.

Answer (score 0):

As of December 2022, I removed that by going into /content/_index.md and deleting the first "-block:" section